# defining characters to ignore while matching strings C#

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm

I want to match two strings with each other , while minding three conditions:

1-Case sensitivity (should all be case insensitive): wHo<=>Who

2-underscore: father_of <=> father of

3-missing space: barackobama <=> barack obama

So, the following two strings should match each other

Who is the fatherof barack_obama <=> who IS the father of barack obama

I'm not sure where to start, I tried to get permutations of both strings, considering both cases of underscore and missing spaces, so it would be like

```
Who, is, fatherof, barack_obama

who is, is fatherof, fatherof barack_obama,
whois, isfatherof, fatherofbarack_obama,
who_is, is_fatherof, fatherof_barack_obama,

who is fatherof, is fatherof barack_obama
whoisfatherof, isfatherofbarack_obama
who_is_fatherof, is_fatherof_barack_obama

who is fatherof barack_obama
whoisfatherofbarack_obama
who_is_fatherof_barack_obama
```

this is good for matching barack obama with barack_obama but not good in vice versa, even if I'm able to split a string with undserscore in between, I cannot do that with the missing space

Comment: You are expected to ask a question, not assign a task.

Comment: @HansPassant you'll get `How can I do that?` ;)

Comment: Well, it's a reasonable guess I guess.  I can't guess why we have to guess.

Comment: @HansPassant - I hope you don't code like you comment ;)

Answer (score 6):

Maybe do:

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
  private string NormalizeText(string text)
  {
    return text..Replace("_","")
                .Replace(" ","")
                .Replace(",","");

  }

  public static bool CustomEquals(this string instance, string otherString)
  {
    return NormalizeText(instance).Equals(NormalizeText(otherString),
                                          StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
  }
}
```

So

```
"Who is the fatherof barack_obama"
"who IS the father of barack obama"
```

is compared like (Ignoring case)

```
"Whoisthefatherofbarackobama"
"whoISthefatherofbarackobama"
```

Comment: Yeah, that's probably more readable than leveraging a Regex. +1

Comment: Updated to match using NEW criteria added by OP (comma).

Comment: Feature creep on stackoverflow. I've been noticing that trend; ask fast, modify as answers start coming in. It makes sense to make a question better - but this kind of homework PLZ GIMME CODE stuff...

Comment: Typically a VERY good indication of a XY Problem http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378

Comment: ...and they can be fun to answer sometimes, just to work the brain muscles. But it's like feeding the ducks at the park.

Comment: Feeding the ... http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2010/02/the-nonprogramming-programmer.html

Answer (score 2):

A little shorter version with regular expression used for removing characters:

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static bool CustomEquals(this string current, string other)
    {
        string pattern = @"[_\s,]";
        return String.Equals(
            Regex.Replace(current, pattern, String.Empty),
            Regex.Replace(other, pattern, String.Empty), 
            StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
    }
}
```